# Authenticate Http request

Tags: component, custom-component

I'm trying to POST from one controller method to another with the Http class.

```
$http = new Http();
$url = Uri::base().'index.php?option=com_mycontroller&task=my_method';
$response = $http->post($url, []);
die($response->getBody());
```

But it just returns a redirect to the login page.

How can I post to this method with authentication?

Comment: Please take our [tour].

Comment: Is there a reason you need an internal process to go via the internet?

Comment: @jamesgarrett it was for a payment gateway that needed to collect post data then post it to another url. I did it with redirecting back to the page and using JS to submit a hidden form in the end